# Two column layout: first column fixed width, second column consumes remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have two columns, the first one with exactly `width: 3rem`, and the second one with the remaining width.

Also, I would like the text to go to the next line under itself, how is that possible using `flexbox`

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex !important;
}
.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.text-primary {
  color: white;
}

h2:first-of-type {
 background: blue;
 flex: 0 0 3rem;
}

h2:last-of-type {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <H2 class="text-primary">1&nbsp;/&nbsp;</H2>
  <div>
    <H2>Hello World</H2>
    <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea</P>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

h2:first-of-type {
  flex: 0 0 3rem;  /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  background: blue;
}

h2:last-of-type {
  flex: 1;         /* fg: 1, fs: 1, fb: 0 */
  background: red;
}

.text-primary {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 class="d-inline-block text-primary">1 / </h2>
  <h2 class="d-inline-block">Hello world</h2>
</div>

<div>
  <h2 class="d-inline-block text-primary">1 / </h2>
  <h2 class="d-inline-block">Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my snippet. I expect to have `1 / Hello World` to look like one sentence, and the caption text aligned with the letter H of the title. I have tried to use `flex: 0 0 3rem;` but the `/` appear on the next line.

Comment: It seems that it fail if the first `h2` is using space, but work fine with words.

Comment: I'm not at my pc anymore; just on mobile. Regardless, it's not recommended to fundamentally alter a question after answers have been provided and voted on. Consider posting a new question with the new requirements.